# NODE_ENV=development set in .bash_profile but undefined when using it in code

Tags: node.js, macos, unix

My `~/.bash_profile` content:

```
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export NODE_ENV=development
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# {{{
# Node Completion - Auto-generated, do not touch.
shopt -s progcomp
for f in $(command ls ~/.node-completion); do
  f="$HOME/.node-completion/$f"
  test -f "$f" && . "$f"
done
# }}}
```

However in my app.js code my process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined. I've searched for my issue but only find how to set it and I seemed to have followed "how to" correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you starting your `app.js`? Can you verify the environment before executing the script (check the output of `echo $NODE_ENV`)?

Comment: I just used the terminal and echoed $MONGO_PATH and gave me `/usr/local/mongodb` and then tried $NODE_ENV and was blank

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind you'll also need to reload the .bash_profile after editing it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or, alternatively: 
`. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Sir, you win 100 internets.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something within your ~/.bashrc could be overwriting `NODE_ENV` var, but it doesn't really matter, because if you want the default behaviour of your `app.js` be to run as 'development' by default, you just should have something like:

```
var run_mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if(run_mode === 'development'){
   // development mode
}
```